# How to Insert the textfile data to sql server2008

Tags: vb.net

i am new to vb.net, i am working on a project in which i have to insert the data from textfile  to databas sql server 2008 the textfile from which i have to get the data is this

```
30DEC2014|GASF|8980|Golden Arrow|10.74|10.95|10.67|10.85|236500|||
```

but i just want to store  the data in this format

```
30DEC2014|GASF|8980|Golden Arrow|10.74|10.85|236500|||
```

i dnt want to include |10.95|10.67 from this 
please help me how i can achieve this
thanks

Comment: You need to show us what is your actual code. Asking to do you work is a bit too broad. Here, for example, you need to know how to read files, how to split lines, how to connect to a database, how to insert data in tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your text file is in the same delimited format you can just read in the file and then cycle through each row pulling out each delimited group. You then ignore the 7th and 8th group and put the rest into another delimited string which you can then insert into the DB.

You have been a bit ambiguous to exactly how the DB is setup or if you have any other criteria so cant give you anything more than that.

This site can give you an idea on how to read delimited files in VB, would assume you just need to change the comma to a pipe character.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx